# ZoneMinder shows code instead of its control panel

Tags: php, panel

Today I installed [ZoneMinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZoneMinder) (see [GitHub](https://github.com/ZoneMinder/zoneminder) and [home page](https://zoneminder.com))
by following some instructions (if you need to look at them, let me know). 
Well, when I try to open the site, the panel doesn't open. 
Some PHP code opens instead. Can you tell me how to solve this problem?

```
<?php
//
// ZoneMinder main web interface file, $Date$, $Revision$
// Copyright (C) 2001-2008 Philip Coombes 
//
// This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
// modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
// as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
// of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
//
// This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.
//
// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
// along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
// Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307, USA. 
//

error_reporting( E_ALL );

$debug = false; 
if ( $debug )
        ︙
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have your web server (you are fetching the file from a web server, right?) to interpret php. Most likely, you don't have php installed.

For instance, if the web server used apache on a Debian-like system, you could need install the package libapache2-mod-php. If you were using nginx, you should configure it via fastcgi, etc.

The exact steps will depend on your OS, distribution, web server...

Comment: I have a LAMP stack. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Well, you seem to be missing the P of the LAMP. Does a file with just `<?php phpinfo();` work?

Comment: $debug = false;
if ( $debug )
{
    // Use these for debugging, though not both at once!
    phpinfo( INFO_VARIABLES );
    //error_reporting( E_ALL );
}

// Use new style autoglobals where possible
if ( version_compare( phpversion(), "4.1.0", "<") )
{
    $_SESSION = &$HTTP_SESSION_VARS;
    $_SERVER = &$HTTP_SERVER_VARS;
}

// Useful debugging lines for mobile devices
if ( false )
{
    ob_start();
    phpinfo( INFO_VARIABLES );
    $fp = fopen( "/tmp/env.html", "w" );
    fwrite( $fp, ob_get_contents() );
    fclose( $fp );
    ob_end_clean();
}

Comment: the rest of the code from zoneminder is not needed. Your problem is that php are not being interpreted when you access -I assume- http://localhost/ you need to investigate that.

Comment: default page apache2 works

Comment: Yes. Obviously I'm having problems with php ... I'll try to fix

Comment: php fixed it. But he still does not open the pages normally